# Почему при направлении row высота элементов остается неизменной?

Tags: css, flexbox

Вот скрин проблемы, элемент тест хоть и имеет заданную высоту меньше половины - как элемент  flex-а занимает ровно половину и gallery  к нему не прижимается вниз.

[image: Элемент тест хоть и имеет высоту меньше половины, занимает ровно половину и gallery к нему не прижимается вниз]

При выравнивании stretch - так же высота остается половина, независимо от того какая задана :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
CSS родителя такое:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

у вложенных элементов  - только заданная высота у элемента  test

Подскажите как в данном случае убрать фиксированную высоту в половину элемента?

html соответственно:

gallery
  test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Высота остается фиксированной потому что эмелемны растягиваются на всю высоту  flex , которая задана.
Чтоб так не происходило, ннадо убрать height  у  flex,  тогда  height  у элементов не будет игнорироваться

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  
  border:1px solid;
}

.test {
  background: lime;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
  
  margin-top: auto;
}

.gallery {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test">test</div>
  <div class="gallery">gallery</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  
  border:1px solid;
}

.test {
  background: lime;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
  
  margin-top: auto;
}

.gallery {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test">test</div>
  <div class="gallery">gallery</div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно прижать элементы вниз друг к другу, у вас так же как у меня - элемент который выше не прижимается к элементу который ниже, даже если у нижнего установить высоту в 1px

Comment: @Mira, т.е. оба блока должны быть внизу?! теперь понятно)

Comment: @Mira, как раз добавила вариант с column (я так понимаю он не подходит). Да, особенность стандарта.

Comment: спасибо за помощь